# Which join I should use?

Tags: database, join

Let say I say a table called:post. Another table is comments.

And the relationship between post and comments is which comment belong to one post. And one post have many comments.

So, I want to join that two table, which join should I use??

```
Post
id

Comments
id
post_id
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what exactly you want to do, and what foreign keys your database schema has.

Generally, for a 1-to-N relationship (1 post has N comments) you do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` of posts to comments, for example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM post p
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments c ON p.id = c.post_id
```

Comment: +1, You do a left outer join, instead of an inner join, because you want to return a post, even if it has no comments.